# Drupal Webform Preview Page: Adding Bullets on Conditional Elements (theming)

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform, theming

There seems to be some kind of bug in webform or I'm doing it wrong. On the preview page of a webform, conditional based selections like checkboxes still display regardless of whether they are selected by the user or not. The code show in the source and a blank space will show if nothing is selected.

I just created a test page with three select components (multiple select checkboxes with only one choice ) and placed component A checkbox (in a fieldset) is on the level above the other two that are within a fieldset as well.

So for example,

```
Selection 'A' fieldset
>> Selection 'A' checkbox
>>>> Selection 'B' fieldset
>>>>>>>> Selection 'B1' checkbox (separate component)
>>>>>>>> Selection 'B2' checkbox (separate component)

The conditional set is like so.
IF: >> Selection 'A' checkbox is EMPTY
THEN >>>> Selection 'B' fieldset
ISNT SHOWN
```

The point of all this is that I need to place the selected options checkboxes in a bullet list but the bullets points still show on the preview page with out the words, even if those answers aren't selected. I added the bullets using css. I think the following code from this link might be on the right track but I'm not sure how to get it to work for the preview page.

https://www.drupal.org/node/79086

```
function phptemplate_webform_form_50 ($form) {
 $form['submitted']['First Name']['#id'] = 'edit-submitted-first-name';
 $form['submitted']['Last Name']['#id'] = 'edit-submitted-last-name';
 $form['submitted']['Fluent in']['#id'] = 'edit-submitted-fluency';
 return _phptemplate_callback('webform_form_50', array('form' => $form));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditions should work. A temp solution would be to hide both the check boxes if Selection 'A' is empty.

Comment: You don't need to add "thanks" to answers.  Posts should be free of noise.